# Work around for x64 bit limit - Worksheet.change

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is I'm trying to make a sheet that update the date on the row where data is being edit.

But I have around 600 rows, and the limit for the one code (Worksheet_change) is by far exceeded before I reach the bottom.

My code is like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E7:AR7"), Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Range("AS7") = Range("A1")
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E8:AR8"), Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Range("AS8") = Range("A1")
End If
```

Just continues up to 600+. (I have a spreadsheet to write the code for me, so not that much work)
But it is when I didn't thought about the limit.

Is there a workaround or some similar code that gets the job done?

Just to make it Clear what I'm trying to do, if it isnt from the code itself.
When a user edit some data between E7:AR7 then AS7 = today()
And down the rows.

E8:AR8 then AS8 = today()

E9:AR9 then AS9 = today()

E10:AR10 then AS10 = today()

-##-

Hope you guys have some ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate If statement for each range.

The code below will check for changes in `E7:AR700` and put the value from `A1` in column `AS` of the row that's been changed.

You can adjust `E7:AR700` to suit.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E7:AR700"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rng In Target.Cells
            Range("AS" & rng.Row) = Range("A1")
        Next rng
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh yeah, Perfect :D!

Didn't thought about that at all, Worked like a charm, much better. felling silly now :)

And really thank for the quick answer damn :)

Comment: You should note that if the user updates multiple rows at once then this only captures the first row.